# Trying to find a managed multilingual wiki service

Tags: project-management, wiki, multilingual

I'm trying to find an online collaboration service such as http://www.comindwork.com/ which contains features for a multilingual wiki. CoMindwork has a wiki, but its not multilingual.

There is the possiblity of hosting our own (Win2003, .NET), but I'd rather have a bunch of project management tools available from the one service

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Darren, Comindwork supports many languages (26 langs provided by Google Translate). You can switch to any of them after login.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **[Screw Turn Wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/)**

- Multilanguage interface (English, Italian, French, Spanish, German and 13 other languages)
- Free and Open Source